# Renaming multiple files with multiple field separator in awk

Tags: command-line, rename

I need to rename following file likewise from **P**FSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData**20211008**.zip to **T**FSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData**20211104**.zip.

Every file's name should start with "T" and end up with current system date + .zip"

I am trying to loop over files and it looks like this:

```
for FILENAME in PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211008; do
    NEW_FILENAME_HEADER=`echo $FILENAME | awk -F "." '{ print $1"."$2"."$3 }'` # which would takes PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.
    NEW_FILENAME_SUFFIX=`echo $FILENAME | awk -F "[.|Data20]" '{ print "."$4 }'` # this part where I can't figure out to take only "FSIContract"
    NEW_FILENAME="${NEW_FILENAME_HEADER}.""${NEW_FILENAME_SUFFIX}""Data20""${DATE}".zip" # which should make "TFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211104.zip."
    mv $FILENAME $NEW_FILENAME
  done
```

FYI `$DATE` in our script defined like this: DATE=`'date +'%y%m%d'` for example 211104

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about and then let us know if you still have a question. Also don't use all upper case variable names, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should get the current date with `date +%Y%m%d` (4-digits year) instead of `date +%y%m%d` (2-digits year). The following assumes you do that. Prepend `20` to `$DATE` if it is not an option.

If your file names all look as the example you show bash substitutions can do it. First compute the length, extract the characters from second to last before date, prepend `T`, append `$DATE.zip`:

```sh
len="${#FILENAME}"
NEW_FILENAME="T${FILENAME:1:$((len-13))}$DATE.zip"
```

But you could also use `sed`, it offers a bit more flexibility. For instance it can deal with ending dates on a variable number of digits:

```sh
NEW_FILENAME=$(echo "$FILENAME" | sed 's/.\(.*[^0-9]\)\?[0-9]*\.zip/T\1'"$DATE"'.zip/')
```

Or, a bit more elegant with bash (here strings) and GNU sed or another sed that supports the `-E` option (for extended regular expressions):

```sh
NEW_FILENAME=$(sed -E 's/.(.*[^0-9])?[0-9]*\.zip/T\1'"$DATE"'.zip/' <<< "$FILENAME")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this part (FSIContract)is not same for all files. It changes like this "FSICustomerContact", "FSILocation" and etc.

Comment: This doesn't matter. What the commands I show do is remove the first and 12 last characters. They don't care what's in between. Give them a try.

Comment: But of course yours does work only for PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211008.zip not PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSICustomerContact20211008.zip, PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSILocation20211008.zip

Comment: Alright I will give a try again

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you think it will not work but I tested with your two other examples and it worked like a charm. The first version (bash parameter substitution) works only if the names end with a date on 8 characters followed by the `.zip` extension. The two others with sed tolerate dates on any number of digits.

Comment: NEW_FILENAME=$(sed -E 's/.(.*[^0-9])?[0-9]*\.zip/T\1'"20${DATE}"'.zip/' <<< "$FILENAME") worked perfectly by adding 20 in the beginning of $DATE. Thanks much!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not realize that your `DATE` is on 6 digits only. Why don't you use `date +%Y%m%d` instead of `date +%y%m%d`? Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ugh, that is long story :D But make long story short, I work on automation with shell scripts where we use $DATE to list the other files with the `find` command. Terrible

Answer (score 3):

With Perl's `rename` command you could try following code. I am using `-n` option here to test it in DRY RUN mode it will only print the file names from which file name(current) to which file name(required one) will be changed; remove `-n` in code once you are satisfied with shown output. Also `DATE` variable (`DATE='20211104'`) is a shell variable which contains value of date needed to be in new file name.

```
rename -n 's:^.(.*)\d{8}(\.zip)$:T$1$2:; s:\.zip$:'"$DATE"'.zip:' *.zip
```

Output will be as follows:

```
rename(PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211008.zip, TFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211104.zip)
```

***Explanation of `rename` code:***

- `-n`: To run `rename` command in DRY RUN mode.
- `s:^.(.*)\d{8}(\.zip)$:T$1$2:;`: Running 1st set of substitution in `rename` code. Where it creates 2 capturing group, 1st capturing group has everything from 2nd character onwards to just before 8 digits AND 2nd capturing group contains `.zip` at the end of filename. While substitution substituting it with `T1$2` as per requirement.
- `s:\.zip$:'"$DATE"'.zip:`: Running 2nd set of substitution in `rename` code. Where `.zip$` with shell variable `DATE` along with .zip as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- replace first character (`P` in OP's sample) with `T`
- replace last 10 characters (`YYMMDD.zip`) with `$DATE.zip` (OP has already defined `$DATE`)
- all files contain `20YYMMDD` so we don't need to worry about names containing strings like `19YYMMDD` and `21YYMMDD`

One idea using [parameter substitutions](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) (which also eliminates the overhead of subprocess calls to execute various `echo`, `awk` and `sed` commands):

```
DATE='211104'
FILENAME='PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211008.zip'

NEWFILENAME="T${FILENAME/?}"                           # prepend "T"; "/?" => remove first character
NEWFILENAME="${NEWFILENAME/??????.zip}${DATE}.zip"     # remove string "??????.zip"; append "${DATE}.zip"

echo mv "${FILENAME}" "${NEWFILENAME}"
```

This generates:

```
mv PFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211008.zip TFSI4C.CSC.CCC.FSIContractData20211104.zip
```

Once OP is satisified with the accuracy of the code the `echo` can be removed to enable execution of the `mv` command.